# Availability.h -like macro

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to have a custom availability macro like the __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING for instance. I need it to perform in the same way, I just need to change its name and the versions and number of parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, certainly. Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so C macros are very much at your disposal, and that facility is simply a set of C macros that eventually expand to
[gcc's `__attribute__` keyword to declare special attributes of a function](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

The relevant declarations are all in

- [`Availability.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/Availability.h)
- [`AvailabilityInternal.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/AvailabilityInternal.h)

To refresh, you use the `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING` macro to tag a function declaration as being supported for a particular version, like this:

```
extern void mymacfunc() __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5,__IPHONE_NA);
```

So what do we need to implement this ourselves?  If you strip their
support for two different OS (mac, iphone), the availability facility boils down to:

1. A macro that takes a version argument like `__MY_AVAILABLE_STARTING(<version>)`:

   ```
   #define __MY_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_myversion) __MY_AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_myversion
   ```
2. Set of version arguments, like those in `Availability.h`, that are valid arguments for the above:

   ```
   #define __MYVER_2_0     20000  
   #define __MYVER_2_1     20100  
   #define __MYVER_2_2     20200  
   #define __MYVER_3_0     30000
   ```
3. Another set of macros, like thos in `AvailabilityInternal.h` that specifies what should happen for each version (regular support, deprecated, unavailable, weak, etc). Again, this is a function of the compiler, see [`gcc docs`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (there are lots of other interesting options):

   ```
   #define __MY_AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MYVER_2_0 __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_UNAVAILABLE
   #define __MY_AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MYVER_2_1 __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_WEAK_IMPORT
   #define __MY_AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MYVER_2_1 __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_REGULAR
   ```
4. And finally, where the buck ends, the macros that expand to the `__attribute__` facility.

   For the ones I have above, you can just keep using Apple's macros:

   ```
   #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_DEPRECATED         __attribute__((deprecated,visibility("default")))
   #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_UNAVAILABLE        __attribute__((unavailable,visibility("default")))
   #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_WEAK_IMPORT        __attribute__((weak_import,visibility("default")))
   #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL_REGULAR            __attribute__((visibility("default")))
   ```

   Or, of course, you can define your own craziness.

C Macros are powerful stuff, often overlooked. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply. However I still have one question. Is there a body to these macros or is that all I need to do?

Comment: Nope, that's all there is to it; `#define` just takes two args, identifier and replacement. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html for more info.