# Is there a macro that denotes the iOS SDK version against which the code is compiled?

Tags: ios, xcode

I.e., is it possible to know if my code is compiled under SDK 5.1, or 6.0, or any other version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
    // Will be ignored when compiled under SDK 5.1
#endif
```

When you are compiling under iOS SDK 5.1 or any other older SDK there is no #define for __IPHONE_6_0, so checking if the macro is defined helps to check the SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the file ["`Availability.h`"](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/Availability.h) and ["`AvailabilityInternal.h`"](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/AvailabilityInternal.h) in the iOS SDK and you'll see conditionals that you may be able to make use of. The Apple OpenSource ones that I linked to ([which I found in this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500673/availability-h-like-macro)) aren't the same ones that you'll find in your SDK.

For example, I see a define for "`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`" and if you want to compile this code only on iOS 6 & newer, you'd make certain to have this set to "`__IPHONE_6_0`".

Comment: Unfortunately, the logical goal is not to restrict iOS versions, so that won't work well. I thought about inferring the SDK from existing defines of iOS version (__IPHONE_X_Y), but I'd like to see if there's anything better.